# Displaying image and setContactTestBitMask is not the same

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios7.1, skspritenode

I have the following code

```
static const CGFloat kPipeWidth=56;

(void)topObstacle { 

    Obstacle *pipeTop = [Obstacle spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pipetop-1"];

    [pipeTop setCenterRect:CGRectMake(26.0/kPipeWidth, 26.0/kPipeWidth, 4.0/kPipeWidth, 4.0/kPipeWidth)];

    [pipeTop setYScale:pipeTopHeight/kPipeWidth];   
    [pipeTop setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width+(pipeTop.size.width/2),
        self.size.height-(pipeTop.size.height/2))];   
    [self addChild:pipeTop];

    pipeTop.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:pipeTop.size];   
    [pipeTop.physicsBody setAffectedByGravity:NO];   
    [pipeTop.physicsBody setDynamic:NO];

    [pipeTop.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:kPipeCategory];  
    [pipeTop.physicsBody setCollisionBitMask:kplayerCategory]; 
}
```

The pipe picture is displayed correctly, however the collision area is not correctly set up. What is wrong with my code!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be causing this:

1. I believe the yScale will scale the image down but not change the value when later used to set the physics body size.  (essentially the physics body = original image size)
2. I do not see a contactBitMask which will allow you to check when your (flappy felipe or mario?) comes in contact with the pipe.

To fix this try:

- Draw a rectangle using the same variables you currently use and color it black.  This will show you where the physics body is being drawn.
- set them to have a contact event and then log their contact